# Postgres long SQL script in one transaction or many?

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions

If I have a script something like this

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;
CREATE TABLE my_table AS
SELECT *
FROM some_other_table
JOIN example_table USING (some_column);

lots more code... this all takes an hour to run

-- I raise an exception
SELECT raise_exception_function();
```

My point is, the script builds many tables and does updates and all sorts that takes over an hour to run.

This is all done in a single transaction and when the function at the end is run and exception is raised. All that hours work will be undone, and so Postgres must store these changes somewhere, I assume in memory etc, which will slow the server.

So, would it be better to split up this long query and run it as individual transactions? This is of course assuming that I do not care for the advantages of having the transaction rolled back so that no changes take effect.

Does it take up more system resources having one long transaction as apposed to many smaller transactions?

Comment: Using more transactions will reduce the overhead of storing intermediate results in the log and is probably a good idea, if you don't care about the transactional semantics.

Comment: I would write this as a comment, but I don't have the reputation yet. Have you considered using a view, if you're just presenting the join result of two tables?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about that, unless you have proof that the long running transaction **is** a problem. Until then, define the transaction the way you need them. And _if_ it starts being a problem, I'd rather try to tune the runtime of the script than give up on the transaction boundary

Comment: The server runs many of these types of "reports" at the same time and so available memory is a big concern to me.